# Python Create Zip File in a Dynamic File System

Tags: python, zip

I'm having trouble creating a zip in my file system which is dynamic depending on what's defined in the `.env` file. Can someone guide me through the correct way of writing the zip file?

Here's what I've come up so far which is I know is incorrect.

```
import os
import zipfile
from fs import open_fs


def download_zip_report():
    try:
        fs = open_fs(os.getenv('UPLOAD_FOLDER').strip("'"))
        with fs.open('/', 'wb') as test_file:
            zf = zipfile.ZipFile('test2.zip', mode='w')
            zf.write('file.txt')
            zf.close()

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(str(e))
        return Response(status=404)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the file system package is used for but the appropriate way to write a zipfile is:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('path/to/zipfile.zip', 'w') as zip_file:
    zip_file.write('path/to/file')
```

Bare in mind that *"...ZipFile is also a context manager and therefore supports the with statement. In the example, myzip is closed after the with statement’s suite is finished—even if an exception occurs.."* (From zipfile — Work with ZIP archives [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)) so you don't have to use zip.close() at the end.
Thus applies to all context manager in Python.

Comment: Just to answer your inquiry regarding the fs package. I am using it because I am uploading files to a remote server (aws), while on dev, I use the local machine. Hope this helps.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for reminding me the 'with statement'. I was also hoping if you can answer whether on how would I be able to add the path if it's from remote or using the fs package.

Comment: what's the value expected to be assigned to fs when running on a server or localhost?